# Why HTML rowspan not working?

Tags: html

I want to put percent at the right in 2 rows cell, but seems like something wrong here:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
   <b style="color: #333;margin-left: 65px;">True Negative</b> 
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="border-top: 2px black solid;">
      <b style="color: #333;">(True Negative + False Positive)</b>
  </td>

  <td rowspan="2">
      <b style="color: #333;">x 100 %</b></td>
  </tr>  

</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8cr7ergj/

Comment: Try moving the cell with x 100 % to the table row above and it should work, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8cr7ergj/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowspan` is the span of rows starting with the current. As your cell is in the last row, there is no other row it could span to. I think, you want something more like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
          <b style="color: #333;margin-left: 65px;">True Negative</b> 
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> 
          <b style="color: #333;">x 100 %</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-top: 2px black solid;"> 
          <b style="color: #333;">(True Negative + False Positive)</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Like that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/qnxorbx3/

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
   <b style="color: #333;margin-left: 65px;">True Negative</b> 
  </td>
  <td rowspan="2">
      <b style="color: #333;">x 100 %</b></td>
  </tr>  
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="border-top: 2px black solid;">
      <b style="color: #333;">(True Negative + False Positive)</b>
  </td>


</table>
```